# Parameter binding With Nested Objects in ASP.NET Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have following model classes in my project:

```
public class RiskInfo
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the risk id.
    /// </summary>
    public string RiskId { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the risk address.
    /// </summary>
    public PropertyAddress RiskAddress { get; set; }
}

public class PropertyAddress
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the street number.
    /// </summary>
    public string StreetNumber { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the name of the street.
    /// </summary>
    public string StreetName { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the city.
    /// </summary>
    public string City { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the county.
    /// </summary>
    public string County { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the state.
    /// </summary>
    public string State { get; set; }
}
```

I have an action method in my controller that is defined like:

```
    [GET("hydrantflow/riskinfo")]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetFlowTestByRiskInfo([FromUri]RiskInfo riskInfo)
```

I am trying to call this action method from Fiddler by using this URL:

```
http://localhost:63932/hydrantflow/riskinfo?riskid=49WY99000191&streetnumber=900&streetname=pine%20st&city=pinedale&state=wy
```

but when I debug my action method, I see that only riskInfo.RiskId property is populated, riskInfo.RiskAddress stays null. However, if I change the above URL to

```
http://localhost:63932/hydrantflow/riskinfo?riskid=49WY99000191&riskaddress.streetnumber=900&streetname=pine%20st&city=pinedale&state=wy
```

I see that the riskInfo.RiskAddress.StreetNumber is now 900. It seems like I need prefix all the parameters in my URL with the property name "riskaddress" that doesn't seem like the best way to do this.

Is there a better to use parameter binding with nested objects?

Thanks

Comment: You could create a custom parameter binding(ex: deriving from `HttpParameterBinding`) to handle this yourself...but even if you do so i am wondering how would you differentiate between top level properties vs. nested properties..there has to be some kind of logic in differentiating them...

Comment: Are you sure you want to post an object to a GET method ?

Comment: @Shyju: Yes, I don't want to use body for sending parameters while makign a GET call. Although, HTTP doesn't prevent you from doing it, its not usually recommended.

Comment: @Kiran: Yes, I read about HttpParameterBinding but wasn't sure if there is some solution out of the box.